# Gremlin query to get the list of vertex not connected with any other vertex?

Tags: gremlin

I tried something like this g.traversal().V().hasLabel(labelName).where(__.bothE().count().is(0)).toList(); it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why your approach wouldn't work - here's an example graph and as you can see it returns the right answer:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property('name','marko').as('m').
......1>   addV('person').property('name','stephen').as('s').
......2>   addV('person').property('name','alice').as('a').
......3>   addE('knows').from('m').to('s').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().where(bothE().count().is(0)).valueMap()
==>[name:[alice]]
```

Perhaps you should check your data more closely to be sure it contains the structure that you expect. While your way worked, I think I would take this approach:

```
gremlin> g.V().where(__.not(bothE())).valueMap()
==>[name:[alice]]
```

In this way, you don't force a `count()` of all the edges to detect the edge existence when you are just looking for the absence of any edges.

Comment: Tried the 2nd one still not getting result.Even not getting error.DB is Orient DB

Comment: It could be a bug in orientdb. this works on TinkerGraph and virtually every other graph i'm familiar with. what happens when you do `g.V().local(bothE().count())` do you see zeroes in the output?

Comment: g.traversal().V().hasLabel(label).where(__.not(__.bothE())).toList();                    I got the count with this . Thank you

Comment: I assume you just didn't static import the `not()` and `bothE()` from the `__` class. please accept the answer since it looks like it solved your problem